# CakePHP change format in a list input

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I send from a controller this query:

```
$tareas = $this->Tests->Tareas->find('list', [
            'limit' => 200, 
            'keyField' => 'id', 
            'valueField' => 'Fecha'
        ]);
```

The valueField 'Fecha' is a date in my database.

So far so good, but in the view this date field show in 'M-d-Y' format and i want 'dd-MM-yyyy' format.

The problem is that i use input for show a list of dates and i don't know to change the format.

My view have:

```
echo $this->Form->input('tarea_id', [
                'options' => $tareas,
            ]);
```

**How i can to change this date format in $tareas?** 
I try with:

```
Cake\I18n\I18n::locale('es-ES');
```

But this only sawpping order of day by month.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much reading and practice, I have found a partial solution. I wanted to change the date format only in that object. But this solution is good for the moment.

I change to configuration of file **config/bootstrap.php**

In the position of this file:

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', Configure::read('App.defaultLocale'));
```

Changed to:

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'es_ES');
Cake\I18n\Date::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-YYYY');
Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-YYYY');
Cake\Database\Type::build('date')
    ->useImmutable()
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat('dd-MM-YYYY');
```

This gets reformat all site dates with the format indicated.

If there is another solution would be appreciated,

Thank all for reading me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your using Cakephp 3.0

I found a better solution, is go to **config/app.php** file.

look for;

```
'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
        'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
        'base' => false,
```

edit the line to suit your local;

for ireland its;

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_IE'),
```

spain;

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_ES'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create entity in model/entity/ for example your model name is users so you can create bellow entity

**User.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity {

       protected function _getList() {
          return date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->_properties['Fecha']));
       }

}
```

Now You can use

```
$tareas = $this->Tests->Tareas->find('list', [
            'limit' => 200, 
            'keyField' => 'id', 
            'valueField' => function ($e) {
                        return $e->get('list');
                    }
        ]);
```

For more information
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs